# Дух как-то странно поднимает вопросы

Tags: поддержка, дух-сообщества

[Алгоритм поиска максимальной суммы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/129360/178988)

Это вопрос с 12 неудалёнными ответами, один из которых принят.
Какие у Духа были причины его поднимать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Принятая анонимная правка http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/129465/revisions ?

Comment: @zRrr, не знал, что у нас есть анонимные правки...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[На странице правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/62611) написано:

> предложено 1 час назад анонимным пользователем

Чтобы увидеть, как это действует, достаточно открыть страницу с вопросом-ответом в режиме инкогнито - [например этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494578/) - и кликнуть "улучшить этот вопрос/ответ". (На "свежих" вопросах и ответах этой функции нет, чтобы анонимы не вносили путаницу.)

Comment: Я думал, правки могут предлагать только зарегистрированные пользователи...